# Share JPA Entites between projects that use different JPA Implemenations

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I have 2 different projects. Lets call one the `Writer`, and the other the `Reporter`.

The `Writer` processes jobs, and persists JPA entities.

The `Reporter`, reads JPA entities, and displays HTML reports.

Both projects write/read to the same database and tables.

`Reporter` however, uses the JPA implementation `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.1.0.0.Final`

while `Writer` uses JPA implementation `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.1.0.1.Final`

There are even some Spring Framework annotations, like `@Configurable`
Here `Reader` uses `Spring 4.0`, while `Writer` uses `Spring 3.2.4`

What I would like to have, is a shared "library", and the `.java` files in the "library" are compiled with each of the projects, at build time.

Both projects use Maven 3.

I understand that this might not be a best practice, but

- it seems better than having duplicate/identical code in 2 projects
- we will not at this time be upgrading `Writer's` maven dependencies.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you only use least common classes and annotations, all will be fine - but if you use Spring 4.0 annotations and want to compile with Spring 3.2.4, it might get messy.

Comment: And, of course, you're limited to using only features of the former JPA version, i.e. 2.0.

Comment: yes, I am not using anything specific to the new versions, I am fine with them working only with the features of the lowest common denominator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would introduce a one more Maven project - core.jar. Move all the common classes there (e.g. all the entity classes and DAO.

Then add the core.jar dependency to the both Writer and Reporter projects.

So common is t common and you can reuse the classes making all changes just once and have difference where necessary.

Comment: wouldn't this require me to do a 'mvn clean install' on the core project? wouldn't then when I use core as a dependency in my other projects, it would then also try to import core's dependencies? so it would add spring 3.2.4 as a maven library in my spring 4.0 based project?

Comment: If you configure it as snapshot the core.jar will be recompiled without clean install

Comment: The core.jar should not have any reference to spring. The spring dependency should be in the end projects. The jar is just classes storage used in the projects. You just add annotations but the annotations is used in the end project where appropriate version of spring is specified.

Comment: ahh ok, that makes sense. so the core project will error in my IDE?

Comment: actually, this works, in eclipse. however, as soon as I move to my servers, where I just have checked out git repositories, if I do a build on 'Reader' it will complain about missing dependency, obviously. if I then try build 'core' and install to the local repository, it will fail, with 'cannot find symbol's.

Comment: yeah, I was not thinking clearly. I just ended up doing a standard jar maven lib, and including in my projects as normal dependency.